# How do I access the GlueJobOperator script_args input arguments in my Glue job script?

Tags: airflow, aws-glue

I have an airflow DAG that uses the GlueJobOperator module to trigger an AWS Glue job. Everything is working fine except that I'm now trying to pass some input arguments through the script_args parameter of the GlueJobOperator like this:

```
script_arguments = {
        "start_date": "2024-01-31",
        "end_date": "2024-02-02"
    }

glue_job_task = GlueJobOperator(
        task_id="trigger_glue_job",
        job_name="attribution_dag_test",
        iam_role_name="AWSGlueServiceRole",
        s3_bucket="aws-glue-assets-191965435652-us-east-1",
        script_args=script_arguments
    )
```

My understanding is that I should be able to access these arguments in my Glue job script.

I've tried a few things like trying to obtain the `script_args` using `getResolvedOptions` like this:

```
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ["JOB_NAME", "start_date", "end_date"])
```

but I'm not having any luck.

Does anyone know how I can access the `script_args`?

Answer (score 0):

Script args should in form `--{key_name}` - two hyphens in the beginning and key name without hyphens, see: [Accessing parameters using getResolvedOptions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-get-resolved-options.html)

In your case your `script_arguments` should looks something like

```py
script_arguments = {
    "--start_date": "2024-01-31",
    "--end_date": "2024-02-02"
}
```